# Cannot get button variable value from html to controller laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Hello i am trying to pass a variable with its value to controller, 
I want to do like this: So i have a table of requests each request has its button aside that calls the modal and together with the modal form i want to pass it to the controller my code till now

The first part where the form that contains each request as a button:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <form method="POST" action="/borrow">
    {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="card-header">Kerkesat</div>
            <div class="card-body px-0">
                <table id="myTable" class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Libri</th>
                        <th>Antari</th>
                        <th>Veprimi</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($bookRequests as $request)
                    @if($request->borrow != null)

                    @else
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$request->book->title}}</td>
                            <td>{{$request->user->name}}</td>
                            <td>

                               <button type="submit" name="btn" value="<?php echo $request->id ?>" onClick="return validate()"><a href="#" onClick="return validate()" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AproveRequestModal">Lejo</a></button>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Vepro</a>

                            </td>

                        </tr>

                    @endif
                    @endforeach

                    </tbody>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The modal for that is inside the main form:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="AproveRequestModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Aprovo Kerkesen</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">


          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="form-control-label">Cakto Daten e Kthimit:</label>
            <select id="borrow_end" name="borrow_end" class="form-control" required>

                                <option value="{{$time = Carbon\Carbon::today()->addDay()->toDateString()}}">Pas 1 dite - {{$time}}</option>
                                <option value="{{$time = Carbon\Carbon::today()->addWeek()->toDateString()}}">Pas 1 jave - {{$time}}</option>
                                <option value="{{$time = Carbon\Carbon::today()->addWeek(2)->toDateString()}}">Pas 2 jave - {{$time}}</option>
                                <option value="{{$time = Carbon\Carbon::today()->addMonth()->toDateString()}}">Pas 1 muaji - {{$time}}</option>

            </select>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclic="confirmSubmit(event)">Save changes</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
            </form>
```

The controller: Here i can not access the value of the button

```
 public function store(Request $request)
        {
            if(!isset($request->borrow_type)){
                $bookRequest = \App\Request::find($request->request_id) ;


                $test = $request->input('btn');
                dd($test);

                $borrow = new Borrow;
                $borrow->request_id = $bookRequest->id;
                $borrow->borrow_start = Carbon::today();
                $borrow->borrow_end = $request->borrow_end;
                $borrow->loaned_by = Auth::id();
                $borrow->status= 'active';

                $borrow->save();



                $bookRequest->status = 'expired';
                $bookRequest->save();

            }
}
```

When i try dd it gives me null for all cases

Comment: try using <input type="button"> instead of <button> element.

Comment: it won`t work it gets the values of the request id and shows them into as the button name but the problem is that i need first to pass my button value to the modal because the submit button is in the modal form

Answer (score 0):

Put this line just above your `button` and remove `value` attribute from your button:

```
<input type="hidden" name="request_id" value="{{ $request->id }}" />
```

Comment: it did not work however i did it by creating a modal foreach request and then assigning the request id from the modal to controller anyway thanks for the advice